# Download a binary with Maven dependency plug-in

Tags: bash, maven

I want to write a simple shell script that uses Maven to download the last version of the .zip deployed at this location:

https://github.com/EBIBioSamples/EBIBioSamples.github.io/tree/maven-repo/uk/ac/ebi/fg/myequivalents-rdf/1.1-SNAPSHOT

(that is the file myequivalents-rdf-1.1-20161007.151102-1.zip as of today).

I'm trying to use dependency:copy this way:

```
mvn dependency:copy \
  -DremoteRepositories=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/EBIBioSamples/EBIBioSamples.github.io/maven-repo \
  -DgroupId=uk.ac.ebi.fg -DartifactId=myequivalents-rdf -Dversion=1.1-SNAPSHOT -Dartifact=zip \
  -Dtransitive=false -DoutputDirectory=/tmp
```

But it keeps saying "Either artifact or artifactItems is required". I've tried artifact=jar (just to see if it download the .jar instead) and -DartifactItems in place of artifact, but no luck. So, is this possible with Maven? How? The reason I want to use Maven is that it should be faster/cleaner than downloading maven-metadata.xml, extracting the timestamp and using it to build the final URL.

Comment: To download a single artifact you should use [dependency:get](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/get-mojo.html) instead of dependency:copy

Comment: @khmarbaise no, get is to download a .jar on the local repository, I want a different distribution file downloaded on a directory.